# CSS pseudo-class for links to pages in browser favorites

Tags: css, firefox, hyperlink, pseudo-class, favorites

I can style visited links with `a:visited`. I want to the same for links to pages I have in my browser favorites.

I wonder if Firefox has a pseudo-class for that.

Then I could style them with the addon "Stylish".

Answer (score 2):

There's a good reason this doesn't exist: It can be used in conjunction with `getComputedStyle` to invade your privacy (using javascript to report what you may have bookmarked).

This was also a problem with the `:visited` selector and Mozilla rectified it:

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

I suppose they could do the same for `:bookmarked` or something, but as of now this doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder if Firefox has a pseudo-class for that.

I could not find anything [in this list of Mozilla-specific CSS extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions#Pseudo-elements_and_pseudo-classes) that does what you want, so most likely there isn't such a pseudo-class.

There is definitely no such pseudo-class in standard CSS, though, but I think you already know that since you're asking specifically about a Firefox extension.